# MYSQL column type for only positive number bigger or equal to 0?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to ask to what i must se my MYSQL column type so always the value there will be 0 or greater and never like number `-15`.

I need it for one my PHP script which is calculating differences and i don't want to get a result in my column smaller then 0.

I want when it calculate in case 20 - 30 to set in my MYSQL column 0 not -10 if you get what i want.

So is there any chance this will be done with MySQL comumn type?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use `new_column int(11) unsigned`

Comment: I must admit, anticipating for code was a lot better...

Comment: which connector are you using? It's one thing to want your database to force "positive only", but if your PHP code can generate negative numbers, your connector/API/sqllib should also be told to reject attempts to insert data with negative values. On top of that, as the system designer you are also responsible for making sure you never get to that part, checking the data you're going to insert for negative values and not even reaching the "trying to insert" code path if negative numbers occur. Remember, you're in the driving seat.

Comment: It seems a bit strange to do part of the logic in php and part in mysql. If you are calculating in php, why don't you just make sure that the result is never less than 0?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `UNSIGNED` integer types for your columns for holding only positive values, but when you're doing calculations in SQL I'm pretty sure you're always going to end up with a negative number if you subtract a large number from a smaller one. Even if you somehow forced mySQL to use an unsigned INT internally you would *not* end up with zero, you would end up with integer *underflow* and get a huge positive number instead.

Apply *logic operations*. If the number is less than zero, then replace it with zero.